# Words request: "Top" and "bottom" (of a page)

Tags: word-requests

I am localising my app to Japanese.

In the app, there is an option to set the position of the image (イメージの位置) on a page that is going to be printed. It can be either on the top of the page, or at the bottom of the page.

I need to translate the words "top" and "bottom", basically.

Currently, I am using 上 and 下, but I don't think they can be used to describe the position on a page:

[image]

I searched on jisho.org and found 頂上 and 底部, but I don't think they are "exact" opposites like 上 and 下. Or are they? I thought the antonym of 底部 was 頂部 but I am not sure if that is a word (I can't find it on jisho.org)

Can anyone suggest a pair of opposites that means top and bottom.

Comment: Do you mean "上部" "下部"?  Another expression is 上のほう、下のほう, so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot looks perfect to me. 上 and 下 will work just fine for this purpose. 上部 and 下部 would be equally okay.

頂上 is only for the top of a mountain or a similar structure. For some reason, I don't see the kanji 底 often used to refer to the bottom coordinate of a screen, a window, etc.